# Solve the recurrence $f(n+1)=f(n)^2,\, f(0)=2$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relation

I have a problem with an exercise asking me to solve the following recurrence:
$$f(n+1)=f(n)^2, \quad f(0)=2$$
Can someone explain how to solve this? I tried but couldn't.

Comment: Your edit radically changed the question, and invalidated all of the existing answers.  Please don't do that.

Comment: Try "running" the recurrence a few steps, guess an answer, prove by induction.

Comment: This is a dump of an exercise problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/) for our homework policy, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594) for a relevant discussion. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/). If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: You know that f(0)=2 and by substituting that f(0 + 1) = f(0)^2 = 2^2 = 4.  You substitute again and see that f(1 + 1) = f(1)^2 = 4^2 = 16.  Etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(n) = 2^{2^n}$ will solve the recurrence.

- $f(0) = 2^1 = 2$
- $
  f(n+1) = 2^{2^{n+1}} = 2^{2\cdot 2^n} = \left(2^{2^n}\right)^{2} = f(n)^2
  $

Comment: but you are just guessing that f(n)=2^2^n do i need to find it or just to guess

Comment: In general, you always solve a recurrence relation by showing that a particular $f$ satisfies both the initial condition and the relation. How we arrived at $f$ is not of any concern.

Comment: @Roben There are a few methods to solve recurrence relations, among them "guessing" + induction. The "guessing" part of that method basically consists of trying the first couple of values to see whether you can spot a pattern. If you want to read about this stuff, a professor at my university who teaches one of the courses on efficient algorithms included a chapter on solving recurrences, which can be found [here](http://wwwmayr.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/lehre/2013WS/ea/split/main.pdf). It is a little theory-heavy, though.

Comment: @Roben Just wanted to add that this is generalizable to any exponent $k\in N$. $$f(n+1)=f(n)^k, f(0)=k$$.

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).

Answer (score 4):

Hint, Consider the function $g(n) = \log_2 f(n)$

Answer (score 3):

We are given $f(n+1) = f(n)^2$. Now, recursively write $f(n)$ also in the given form. So, if we write it recursively we get the following equations$$f(n+1)=f(n)^2$$ $$f(n)=f(n-1)^2$$ So, using above two equations, $$f(n+1)=f(n-1)^4$$ This doesn't seem to give any hint (If you see any pattern here, great). So, expand more. $$f(n-1) = f(n-2)^2$$ Putting it again in the equation gives, $$f(n+1) = (f(n-2)^2)^4 = f(n-2)^8$$ Now, the patterns becomes clear. For each value you subtract from $n$, power of the function value multiplies by 2. So, we can generalize saying $$f(n+1)=f(n+1-x)^{2^x}$$ We have not yet made use of the base case given. We know $f(0) = 2$. So, put $x=n+1$. We get $$f(n+1) = 2^{2^{(n+1)}}$$ Finally, we get our answer $f(n) = 2^{2^n}$.

This is basically what Priyatham has said, but there is also a way of making guesses. It's not left entirely to your luck

Comment: Can you solve also this one 
Prove the recurrence solution :

    f(n)=  { 2                   n=1  ----------------------------------------------------------------
           { f(n-1)+3=3n-1    otherwise

Comment: Try to solve it!!

Comment: @Roben We won't do your homework for you.

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).

Comment: Oh.. Will try to follow it next time. Thanks